# android - Transparent Navigation Bar but not Status Bar

Tags: android, statusbar, navigationbar

I am not sure if it is possible but I am trying to make the Navigation Bar transparent without making the Status Bar transparent. The reason for the later is I have a Toolbar that would otherwise draw behind the status bar.

Right now I am using a fakeStatusBar Layout that displays before the status bar so everything looks good to the user:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        //now the status bar is transparent too, which we have to fix

        //first we get status bar height
        int statusBarHeight = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        //then we get the full width
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;

        //then we set that height to the fake item in the layout
        LinearLayout fakeStatusBar = findViewById(R.id.fakeStatusBar);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = fakeStatusBar.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = statusBarHeight;
        params.width = screenWidth;
        fakeStatusBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The only problem is when going to multitasking, the thumbnail does not look good because the toolbar is not where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what I wanted but I found a workaround using Translucent Navigation Bar. The final code looks something like this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){

        //set navigation bar translucent
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        //now the status bar is translucent too, which we have to fix

        //first we get status bar height
        int statusBarHeight = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        //then set it as top padding for the main layout
        ConstraintLayout mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setPadding(0,statusBarHeight,0,0);
    }
```

Where top padding is added to the main layout of the activity.

If anyone knows how to do something similar with transparent navigation bar, perfect, but otherwise I am happy with my solution.

Comment: Try to rotate your screen. There will be uncompleted colored rectangle in status bar.

Comment: even if it doesn't work with rotation it worked well for the portrait mode, after an hour of searching for the solution, at leas it worked